# Sorting a 2d array using built in c++ sort function

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, stl

I was trying to sort an array of type `int[1000][2]` based on its first entry(`int [i][0]`), and I used the sort function in the STL and wrote my own comparison object.  But when compiled it says that array type int[2] is not assignable.  What is the problem with my code?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<algorithm>
class op {
public:
    bool operator()(int a[2], int b[2]) {
        return a[0] < b[0];
    }
};
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int money = 0;
    int a[1000][2] = { 0 };
    int total = 0, n = 0;
    cin >> total>>n;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> a[i][0] >> a[i][1];
    }
    sort(a, a + n - 1, op());//where the problem occurred

    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        if (a[1][i] < total) {
            money = money + a[i][1] * a[i][0];
            total = total - a[i][1];
        }
        else {
            money = money + a[i][0] *total;
            break;

        }
    }
    cout << money << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change your variable from

```
int a[1000][2]
```

to a

```
std::array<std::pair<int, int>, 1000>
```

or

```
std::array<std::array<int, 2>, 1000>
```

Then `std::sort` will just work as you intend since `std::pair` and `std::array` already have an `operator<` defined.

Comment: or a `std::array<int, 2>`, which is the same and preserves the semantics.

Comment: That would be one of the solution, but I just want to know what is the problem with the code that causes the error?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the problem with my code?

In fact c-style arrays cannot be assigned, and `std::sort` calls the assignment operation implicitly. They need to be filled using `std::copy` or alike.

I'd recommend you use a `std::array<std::array<int,2>,1000>` instead of the raw array.